# Continued contact between client and server in RMI application to book flight tickets

Tags: java, interface, server, client, rmi

I've been trying to create an advanced RMI application where a user can book a ticket for a flight on an airline. I have the ticket booking system working, but it doesn't appear to be perfect code and I have a feeling there may be an easier way.

Here is my Interface:

```
public interface BookingIF extends Remote {

    int bookTicket(int destination) throws RemoteException;
    void checkAvailable(int journey) throws RemoteException;

}
```

My Server:

```
public class Server extends RemoteObject implements BookingIF {


int madrid = 3;
int london = 3;
int krakow = 3;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try { 
        BookingIF obj = new Server();           
        BookingIF stub = (BookingIF) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject( obj , 0);
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1098);
        registry.bind("RemoteObject", stub);

        System.out.println("Server running...");

        } 
    catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("Server err: " + e.getMessage()); 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}

public int bookTicket(int journey) {
    if (journey > 3) {
        System.out.println("Error, press number between 1 and 3");
    } else {
        checkAvailable(journey);
    }

    return journey;
}

public void checkAvailable(int journey) {
    if(journey == 1) {
        if (madrid != 0) {
            madrid--;
            System.out.println("Journey to madrid booked");
            System.out.println("Number of tickets left for madrid : " + madrid);
        }
    }
    else if(journey == 2) {
        if (london != 0) {
            london--;
            System.out.println("Journey to london booked");
            System.out.println("Number of tickets left for london : " + london);
        }

    } 
    else if(journey == 3) {
        if (krakow != 0) {
            krakow--;
            System.out.println("Journey to krakow booked");
            System.out.println("Number of tickets left for krakow : " + krakow);
        }
    }

}

}
```

And my Client:

```
public class Client {

private Client() {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int message; 
    BookingIF obj = null; 
    try { 
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", 1098);
        obj = (BookingIF) registry.lookup("RemoteObject");
        System.out.println("Press 1 for Madrid");
        System.out.println("Press 2 for London");
        System.out.println("Press 3 for Krakow");
        int numEntered;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        numEntered = scan.nextInt();
        message = obj.bookTicket(numEntered);
        System.out.println(message);
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("Client exception: " + e.getMessage()); 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is after booking a ticket I'm not completely sure how to go back to the client to allow them to purchase another ticket.

I feel there should be away of doing it an easier way, but I can quite wrap my head around the RMI. Could anyone possibly help me?

Comment: You mean, like using a loop of some kind?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, but the only way I could think of doing it is if I create a new BookingIF object.

Comment: Why?  Create the booking object then wrap the rest of the code in a loop...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with this loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int message; 
    BookingIF obj = null; 
    try { 
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", 1098);
        obj = (BookingIF) registry.lookup("RemoteObject");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Press 1 for Madrid");
            System.out.println("Press 2 for London");
            System.out.println("Press 3 for Krakow");
            System.out.println("Press 9 to exit");

            int numEntered;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            numEntered = scan.nextInt();

            if (numEntered == 9) {
                break;
            }
            message = obj.bookTicket(numEntered);
            System.out.println(message);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("Client exception: " + e.getMessage()); 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped. My only problem with that is that it only shows the amount of tickets left when they are all gone instead of printing them after each purchase.

Comment: @jf95 It's probable that the `System.out`s for the `Server` are been printed on the server.  You might need to provide some more info methods for the client to get the information and print it it self

Comment: @jf95 as MadProgrammer said, the messages you print on the server, **will only show up on the server**, not on the client. But that is another question.

Answer (score 0):

A few comments on the RMI part.

```
public class Server extends RemoteObject
```

Make that `extends`UnicastRemoteObject.`

```
     implements BookingIF {

int madrid = 3;
int london = 3;
int krakow = 3;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try { 
        BookingIF obj = new Server();           
        BookingIF stub = (BookingIF) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject( obj , 0);
```

If you extend `UnicastRemoteObject` you can remove this line, and pass the remote object itself to the `bind()` call below instead of the stub.

```
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1098);
```

`registry` should be static. Otherwise it can be garbage-collected, which will shut down the whole program.

```
        registry.bind("RemoteObject", stub);
```

See above.

```
        System.out.println("Server running...");

        } 
    catch (Exception e) { 
        System.out.println("Server err: " + e.getMessage()); 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}

public int bookTicket(int journey) {
    if (journey > 3) {
        System.out.println("Error, press number between 1 and 3");
```

It's no good printing that. It's the server, not the client. The client won't see that. The validation of the input should be in the client, not here.

```
    } else {
        checkAvailable(journey);
    }

    return journey;
}

public void checkAvailable(int journey) {
    if(journey == 1) {
        if (madrid != 0) {
            madrid--;
            System.out.println("Journey to madrid booked");
            System.out.println("Number of tickets left for madrid : " + madrid);
```

See above. Probably the method should return a `boolean` indicating success or failure.
            }

It would be useful to print something here as an `else` case, to indicate there are no tickets left. Same applies below.

```
    }
    else if(journey == 2) {
        if (london != 0) {
            london--;
            System.out.println("Journey to london booked");
            System.out.println("Number of tickets left for london : " + london);
        }

    } 
    else if(journey == 3) {
        if (krakow != 0) {
            krakow--;
            System.out.println("Journey to krakow booked");
            System.out.println("Number of tickets left for krakow : " + krakow);
        }
    }

}

}
```